# Finding the minimum switching expression for this output

Tags: digital-logic, decoder

[image]

Did I do this correctly?

```
Step 1: [(mo' * m1' * m9' * m11') + (m9' + m11' + m13' + m15')]'
Step 2: ... apply demorgan's... resulting in....
Step 3: (mo + m1 + m9 + m11) * (m9 + m11 + m13 + m15)
Step 4: Drew K-Kaps for the 1st and second sums-of-products resulting in:
Step 5: [(W' X' Y') + (W X' Z)]*[WZ]
Step 6: Distribute WZ across the sum.... resulting in:
Step 7: WZ(W'X'Y') + WZ(W X' Z) <-- W cancels in 1st product, WZ is redundant
        in the 2nd
Step 8: Leaving me with (Z X' Y') + (Z X' W)
Step 9: can this be further simplified?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this bit:

> ```
> Step 3: (mo + m1 + m9 + m11) * (m9 + m11 + m13 + m15)
> ```

Only two possible input conditions can cause this to evaluate true: m9 (`WX'Y'Z`) and m11 (`WX'YZ`).

```
WX'Z
```

Comment: Can you tell me where I went wrong with my further simplification using K-MAP?

Comment: Also, you goofed in the first term of step 7; `AA'` is `0`.